# How to check whether the MILP has feasible solutions or not in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I would like to know if there is a fast way to check that a MILP with given inputs has or has no feasible solutions. I have a MILP formulation and am trying to randomly generate inputs of the problem which might or might not have feasible solutions. I want to check this by using CPLEX.

I am aware that one way to check whether the problem has feasible solutions is to set the objective function to be constant (e.g., 0) so that CPLEX will return the first feasible solution found. This might be a fastest way if the inputs we generate somehow have feasible solutions.

What if we somehow generate the inputs of the problem which do not have feasible solutions, I would like to know what would be the fastest way to check that the generated inputs have no feasible solutions by using CPLEX.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, feasibility is as hard as optimality, so usually you have to solve a MIP one way or another. One way to detect (in)feasibility is indeed to zero out the objective and then see whether CPLEX finds a feasible solution or not. However, depending on your problem structure, a meaningful objective value may work better than an all-0 objective. You can set the "solution limit" parameter to 1 so that CPLEX stops at the first feasible solution in that case.

Another option is to use CPLEX's feasopt feature, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/infeas_unbd/feasopt/01_feasopt_title_synopsis.html). CPLEX attempts to find a minimal relaxation. It starts with a problem that is *always* feasible. If your original model is feasible then feasopt will eventually terminate with a solution of objective value 0. If your initial model is infeasible then CPLEX's best bound for the feasopt model will eventually exceed 0 and at this point the algorithm can be stopped. This is sometimes faster to find infeasibility.

Comment: Dear Daniel, Thank you so much for your suggestion. It helps a lot.